# How to convert time zones in oracle?

Tags: oracle, time, timezone

I have a list from peoplesoft timezones which i need to convert using From_TZ method. The time zones will be in a format as EST,IST..etc.

```
select FROM_TZ (CAST ( (:dt) AS TIMESTAMP), 'EST')
          AT TIME ZONE 'IST' from dual
```

Comment: Could you explain what does not work in your sample code ?

Comment: these zone names doesnt work in oracle is there a way to collaborate peoplesoft timezones list and have them use in oracle query for time zone conversion

Comment: Define "doesn't work".  You're getting an error?  What error?  The code you posted is using hard-coded time zones so it's not getting time zones from the caller, it's just getting the `:dt` bind variable (which is, perhaps, a `date`?) from the caller.  Are you implying that your actual code is getting the time zones as bind variables as well?

Comment: Not sure this is what you are looking for, but if you have to fix that on a case-by-case basis, maybe worth looking a `select * from V$TIMEZONE_NAMES` for the corresponding TZ names ? `IST` does not appears on my home system. But `EST` is definitively present.

Comment: In Oracle when i run the above query i get an error such as "Time zone region not found" yes the parameter :dt is just a bind variable for date time value. This query works fine if i use "America/Ney_york" instead of EST and "Asia/Calutta" instead of IST but i need to use peoplesoft version of time zone list which uses 2 letter time zone names but doesnt seem to work in oracle

Answer (score 1):

`IST` does not work, because it is ambiguous, see this table:

```
SELECT tzabbrev, TZ_OFFSET(tzname), tzname  
FROM V$TIMEZONE_NAMES tz WHERE tzabbrev IN ('EST', 'IST')
ORDER BY 1,2,3;

TZABBREV    TZ_OFFSET(TZNAME)   TZNAME
EST +10:00  Australia/Brisbane
EST +10:00  Australia/Lindeman
EST +10:00  Australia/Queensland
EST +10:30  Australia/Broken_Hill
EST +10:30  Australia/Yancowinna
EST +11:00  Australia/ACT
EST +11:00  Australia/Canberra
EST +11:00  Australia/Hobart
EST +11:00  Australia/LHI
EST +11:00  Australia/Lord_Howe
EST +11:00  Australia/Melbourne
EST +11:00  Australia/NSW
EST +11:00  Australia/Sydney
EST +11:00  Australia/Tasmania
EST +11:00  Australia/Victoria
EST -05:00  America/Cayman
EST -05:00  America/Detroit
EST -05:00  America/Fort_Wayne
EST -05:00  America/Grand_Turk
EST -05:00  America/Indiana/Indianapolis
EST -05:00  America/Indiana/Marengo
EST -05:00  America/Indiana/Vevay
EST -05:00  America/Indianapolis
EST -05:00  America/Iqaluit
EST -05:00  America/Jamaica
EST -05:00  America/Kentucky/Louisville
EST -05:00  America/Louisville
EST -05:00  America/Montreal
EST -05:00  America/New_York
EST -05:00  America/Panama
EST -05:00  America/Thunder_Bay
EST -05:00  Canada/Eastern
EST -05:00  EST
EST -05:00  EST5EDT
EST -05:00  Jamaica
EST -05:00  US/East-Indiana
EST -05:00  US/Eastern
EST -05:00  US/Michigan
EST -06:00  America/Cancun
EST -06:00  America/Chicago
EST -06:00  America/Indiana/Knox
EST -06:00  America/Indiana/Petersburg
EST -06:00  America/Indiana/Vincennes
EST -06:00  America/Knox_IN
EST -06:00  America/Managua
EST -06:00  America/Rankin_Inlet
EST -06:00  CST
EST -06:00  US/Central
EST -06:00  US/Indiana-Starke
EST -07:00  America/Cambridge_Bay
IST +00:00  Atlantic/Reykjavik
IST +00:00  Eire
IST +00:00  Europe/Belfast
IST +00:00  Europe/Dublin
IST +00:00  Iceland
IST +02:00  Asia/Gaza
IST +02:00  Asia/Jerusalem
IST +02:00  Asia/Tel_Aviv
IST +02:00  Israel
IST +05:00  Asia/Karachi
IST +05:30  Asia/Calcutta
IST +06:00  Asia/Dacca
IST +06:00  Asia/Dhaka
```

You can use the timezone abbreviation only for following timezones:

```
SELECT tzabbrev, tzname, TZ_OFFSET(tzname) 
FROM V$TIMEZONE_NAMES tz 
WHERE tzabbrev = tzname;

TZABBREV    TZNAME  TZ_OFFSET(TZNAME)
CET CET +01:00
CST CST -06:00
EET EET +02:00
EST EST -05:00
GMT GMT +00:00
HST HST -10:00
MET MET +01:00
MST MST -07:00
PST PST -08:00
WET WET +00:00
```

Important note: When you use the timezone abbreviation like `EST` then you don't get any Daylight-Saving-Time values!