# How to use From_Tz with Offset for time conversion Oracle

Tags: oracle

How can i use From_tz to convert current time zone say EST to IST using offsets. Does this conversion includes Day light saving effect ?

Answer (score 0):

In case your current time zone is `EST` you can do simply this one:

```
SELECT FROM_TZ(TIMESTAMP '2000-03-28 08:00:00', 'Asia/Calcutta') FROM dual;
```

Otherwise you first have to convert to `UTC` or `EST`, i.e.

```
SELECT 
    FROM_TZ(CAST(TIMESTAMP '2000-03-28 08:00:00' AT TIME ZONE 'EST' AS TIMESTAMP), 'Asia/Calcutta'), 
    FROM_TZ(SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(TIMESTAMP '2000-03-28 08:00:00'), 'Asia/Calcutta') 
FROM dual;
```

Note, `IST` is not a valid time zone name in Oracle, see your own question: [How to convert time zones in oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28021915/how-to-convert-time-zones-in-oracle/28024348#28024348)

You can check your current session time zone with function `SESSIONTIMEZONE`

If you like to include them you have to use the full region name, e.g. `America/New_York` or `Asia/Calcutta`. Time zone offset like `+05:00` do not include any Daylight saving effects. For short name it differs, e.g. `EST` does not use DST but `CET` does.

In order to get the "live" offset you have to use `EXTRACT` function:

```
SELECT 
    EXTRACT(TIMEZONE_HOUR FROM FROM_TZ(TIMESTAMP '2015-01-01 00:00:00', 'Europe/Berlin')) offset_winter, 
    EXTRACT(TIMEZONE_OFFSET FROM FROM_TZ(TIMESTAMP '2015-01-01 00:00:00', 'Europe/Berlin')) offset_winter, 
    EXTRACT(TIMEZONE_HOUR FROM FROM_TZ(TIMESTAMP '2015-07-01 00:00:00', 'Europe/Berlin')) offset_summer,
    EXTRACT(TIMEZONE_OFFSET FROM FROM_TZ(TIMESTAMP '2015-07-01 00:00:00', 'Europe/Berlin')) offset_summer
FROM dual;

OFFSET_WINTER   OFFSET_WINTER_1       OFFSET_SUMMER   OFFSET_SUMMER_1
1               +00 01:00:00.000000   2               +00 02:00:00.000000
```

Comment: thanks wenfried but what if i can get UTC offset and DST offset . Can i use these values to manipulate the date time for appropriate time zone conversion .  How can i achieve this in a query?